# How to create multiple mariaDB mysql instance in CentOS 7?

Tags: mariadb

How to create multiple mariaDB mysql instance in CentOS 7? I have already installed first mariaDB mysql instance in CentOS 7. I've been searching for documentations on how to configure a Multi-Master Replication in MariaDB but I can't find any. I use to try some configurations for MySQL but they didn't work. Wsrep were both ON in my two nodes but when I connect the second node to the donor, there's an error while restarting mysql. I'm using CentOS 7 OS. Can someone provide a documentation for MariaDB-Galera cluster Multi-Master Replication?